# Generate PDF Versions On MacOS Through Command Line

Tags: pdf

I'm looking for a simple, lightweight Tex/LaTex PDF compiler that runs on the macOS command line.    I'm currently using www.overleaf.com to compile my Resume, which consists of a `.tex` file and a `.cls` file.  It would be great if it was brew-installable, but it doesn't have to be.  I can't seem to find something like this, it seems the there exists a handful of programs that are all either extremely large or are GUI applications, but I need it to be a command line application so that I can write some scripts to automate the compilation.

I've tried a few different solutions, such as using pandoc and basictex, but I can't seem to find a solution that has similar output as www.overleaf.com.  The PDF styling of the command line applications I've tried seems to be styled differently (this easily be an error on my part) - the command line generated files usually look pretty bad compared to the ones done on www.overleaf.com/.

If anyone knows of a command line application that meets these requirements and can maybe show and example of compiling a project with a `.txt` file and a `.cls` file, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome! `pdflatex` compiles on the console. You can use it as `pdflatex file.tex`. A class file is not supposed to be compiled, it defines the document class that can be "loaded" with `\documentclass`.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Thanks for the suggestion and thanks for the correction.

Comment: I recommend simply installing macTeX. It comes with big GUI components as well as a package-manage app. But most importantly, it will install all terminal commands you will ever need.

Comment: You can install MacTeX with homebrew: `brew cask install mactex-no-gui`

Comment: I'd avoid HomeBrew or similar for installing TeX: either install MacTeX or if you want a smaller system BasicTeX and add the other packages you need.